# Adding deployment server to MDM Studio Designer

Tags: mdm, tibco, tibco-mdm

I'm trying to use TIBCO MDM studio designer for TIBCO MDM and trying to follow studio design tutorial (Repository, Rulebase, Process and UI Builder).

My issue is that I'm trying to add deployment server on Studio Designer, but I can't find it. Is there any plugin missing, or something like that?

My studio designer version is (4.1.0.001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their is one icon on menu toolbar beside the save all which is in blue triangle shape. Click the icon and make sure solution design is checked. [Make sure solution design is checked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjV7e.png)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To enable "Deployment server" go to "Enable/Disable Business Studio capabilities" button and select "Solution Design".
After selecting you will get one popup, you need to say yes for this.
Please refer attached screen shot for more details.

[image]